# Elastix 2.5 - Change settings via WEB GUI does NOT take effect

Tags: linux, git, asterisk, pbx, elastix

My PBX system is currently running Elastix 2.5, which has been installed & configured about three months ago.

For maintaining purpose, I have used `etckeeper` to tracking changes in `/etc` folder, included `asterisk` folder, which is located Elastix's asterisk setting file.

Everything was working fine since then. I have something to modify recently. And, as usually, I've work with the Web GUI. But, I've got a problem. I've changed settings from Web GUI (and even the unembedded `freepbx`): add/delete extensions; change passwords; change `inbound` route destination, etc.. But when I finished my modifies, then `Apply changed settings`, everything is still the same as before.

## I. Two stages of the diagnosic progress:

### 1. Recheck the changes on the Web Gui and `freepbx`:

- Every changes has been saved (as I expected).
- Not even one error notification has been pushed up.
- `asterisk.reload` makes no sense.

### 2. Tracking the changes with `GIT` in `/etc`:

- `git status` gave me the result that nothing has been changed!
- Non of files in `/etc/asterisk` has been modified, every file is at the last state of git log.
- I tried to change files manually: Ah, `git` throws out the changes. `git` works fine. And theses changes take effect after `asterisk.reload`.

## II. Questions:

- I have no idea where to start to diagnostic currently. And I can't figure out exactly what problem is. Please give me some advice, or experiences!
- How to resolve this problem?

Thank you!

## The follow is my PBX Elastix info:

```
Kernel
   Linux(x86_64)-2.6.18-406.el5

 Elastix
   elastix-2.5.0-1
   elastix-a2billing-2.1.0-1.gita40e37fefef7ab85999d04298b6e582b41930e7e
   elastix-a2billing-callback_daemon-2.1.0-1.    gita40e37fefef7ab85999d04298b6e582b41930e7e
   elastix-addons-2.5.0-3
   elastix-agenda-2.5.0-3
   elastix-asterisk-sounds-1.2.3-1
   elastix-email_admin-2.5.0-2
   elastix-endpointconfig2-2.5.0-3
   elastix-extras-2.5.0-1
   elastix-fax-2.5.0-2
   elastix-firstboot-2.5.0-2
   elastix-framework-2.5.0-8
   elastix-im-2.5.0-1
   elastix-my_extension-2.5.0-1
   elastix-pbx-2.5.0-4
   elastix-portknock-0.0.1-0
   elastix-reports-2.5.0-3
   elastix-security-2.5.0-1
   elastix-system-2.5.0-2
```

Answer (score 1):

The reload action converts the configuration stored in the DB to configuration files and then connects to the AMI to reload the configuration, if you connect to the asterisk CLI (asterisk -r) and see a lot of movement when you perform a reload the AMI connection is working (if you have no warnings the reload is probably working correctly).

Make sure that the main conf files (extensions.conf, sip.conf, iax.conf, etc.) have the includes for the corresponding additional files, for example "#include extensions_additionas.conf" in extensions.conf

It is possible that you are having problems with file permissions, make sure that everything inside /etc/asterisk is owned by the asterisk user and group and permissions are set to 664.